# Calculating number of bases that lead to basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $P = \{x \in R^n | Ax \geq b \}$. Suppose that at a particular basic feasible solution, there are $k$ active constraints with $k>n$. Is it true that there exists exactly $C(k,n)$ **bases** that lead to this basic feasible solution?

where,

$C(k,n) = \binom{k}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, it is not true. There is a maximum of $\binom{k}{n}$ bases because there are that many ways to choose $n$ out of $k$ possible bases, but not all combinations have to have linearly independent, so there may be less than $\binom{k}{n}$ bases.

As a counterexample, consider the following 2-dimensional feasible region:
$$
x_1≥1, x_2≥2 \\
-x_1-x_2≥-4 \\
-2x_1-2x_2≥-8 \\
x_1, x_2≥0
$$

With $k=4$ and $n=2$, there are 6 ways to choose 2 constraints from the 4 constraints. However, only 5 lead to a BFS. The last 2 constraints are not linearly independent, and will not lead to a BFS.